# Adding a rodc to an existing domain failed

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, rodc

I want to add a new RODC to an existing domain. 
The new RODC is a Server 2012R2 and the existing domain is a 2008R2 domain. 
The firewall on both sites is offline and both can reach each other per ping and DNS. 
When I want to promote the 2012R2 Server the following error code appears:

```
test.verfiyadprepcredential.adprep.win32exception. -2147467259
```

Furthermore the RPC-service runs, too. I haven't found any suitable 
 information on the internet, yet . Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have other RODC's in the domain? If not, do you know if `adprep /rodcprep` has been run in the forest? RODC's need to be enabled before they can be built. You can query this as follows with powershell:

```
get-adobject "CN=ActivedirectoryRodcUpdate,CN=ForestUpdates,CN=Configuration,DC=your,DC=forest,DC=name" -prop revision
```

The attribute should exist and have Revision=2. If you get a `Directory object not found` it means RODCPrep was never run.
This technet doc shares more info on running RODCPrep https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771055(v=ws.10).aspx
You will need to be use an account that is memeber of Enterprise Admins to run RODCPrep.

Comment: There is no RODC in the domain. I ran adprep without any errors. But the query wasn't sucsessful. The cmdlet could not be found. I couldn't even use "import activedirectory" because the import cmdlet wasn't found. Additional information: The other domain controller is a 2011 small business server.

Comment: Small Business Server 2011 is a different product. The "essentials" supports 25 users and "premium" maxes out with 75 users. With that small a user base I don't know why you'd bother with a RODC. Did you try running DCPromo again after `adprep /rodcprep`? In the future use the `windows-sbs-2011` tag on your posts.

Comment: Indeed it is. I didn't notice it directly. Otherwise I would have tagged it correctly. I am sorry for this. After the adprep /rodcprep command I tried running DCPromo again. But the same error occured again.

Comment: Is the server your trying to promo built with 2012 R2 media, or SBS 2011 media? You probably cannot promo a server built with 2012 R2 media to a SBS 2011 domain. That or `test.verfiyadprepcredential.adprep.win32exception` sounds like you're not using a credential with enough privileges to run the DC Promo.